# Custom Post Type Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: custom-post-types

Okay,

Where is teh custom post type directed to? is it single.php or page.php I have a page.php with a template part that displays each of my custom types but when i click on the item itself i just get 404'd

This is my register custom post type

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'podiums', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'podium', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Podium', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Podium Photos Taken at Nottingham Go Karts', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => false,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'group', $args );
```

my page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <main class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <section id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('podium col-md-12'); ?>>

    <?php query_posts( 'post_type=group&posts_per_page=5'); ?>

    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', 'podium' );

    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>

      </section><!-- Article End -->

    </div><!-- Row End -->
  </main><!-- Section End -->
```

and this is my content-podium.php

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <p>
      View all past groups thats visited Nottingham Go Karts
    </p>

  <ul>

    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

        <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'post-thumbnail') ); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />

      </a>
    </li>


  </ul>
```

Should my page.php actually be displaying the items themselves and the content-podium actually display them singularly ?

Ive googled around and im just getting more and more confused and nothing seems to be working. to see it in action its here http://thomasrenshaw.com/gallery/

Comment: Are you flushing the rewrite rules after registering the post type - flush_rewrite_rules() ??

Comment: Hello, no I don't think I am

Comment: Try to go into the admin, Settings > Permalinks and Save Changes ( which flushes the rewrite rules ).  WP doesn't know how to handle the new post types url / slug yet.

Answer (score 0):

After registering a custom post type, you must flush the rewrite rules so Wordpress knows what the URL / slug should be.

[flush_rewrite_rules()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

Comment: EDIT: HA! im so stupid. there was a 6 in my theme functions haha thank you for the help, youve solved my problem!